# PHP Reading XML Issue

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I need your help once again!

I need to read this xml file... but the problem is that it's not working!

This is the XML

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<item>
<title>Video</title>
<media:content url="http://videourl.com/etc/" type="video/x-flv" duration="5128"/>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://videourl.com/etc/");
echo $xml->getName() . "<media:content url=";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "";
  }

?>
```

And it's not working! It's not working because nothing gets echoed, or printed! Does anyone spot the error?

Comment: Google (or search SO) for `SimpleXML + Namespaces`.

Comment: What is the problem, what is not working?

Comment: You should be a lot more specific than "not working!".  Eg knowing what the output actually is would be helpful.

Comment: Can you try this script? `<?php
print_r (simplexml_load_file("http://videourl.com/etc/")); ?>`.  I think it will print out FALSE, and that due to switched off error reporting your script dies due to this failure.  Please add the result of this test to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<rss> 
    <channel> 
        <item> 
            <title><![CDATA[Tom & Jerry]]></title> 
        </item> 
    </channel> 
</rss>'; 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 

// echo does the casting for you 
echo $xml->channel->item->title; 

// but vardump (or print_r) not! 
var_dump($xml->channel->item->title); 

// so cast the SimpleXML Element to 'string' solve this issue 
var_dump((string) $xml->channel->item->title); 
?>
```

Again i edit my code now try this

Comment: That is not the answer on the question

Comment: @gokcokkececi Now it only shows me part of the code, but not the one I need to use!

Comment: Again i edit my code now try this if this part did not work you should be a lot more specific write error @user2551208